# Debian: disk is remounted as read-only

Tags: debian, proxmox

I have a VM in Proxmox running Debian. After a sudden power failure I've got problems with this VM and it seems due to the fact that the disc has been remounted as read only.
Docker is complaining /var/lib/docker is read only and will not start.

fsck dev/sda1 shows 'clean' as output

fstab can't be edited because it's read only, but the line responsible for the initial remount is commented out (but can't change this)
how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

ok this was easy, and as often found the answer right after posting the question;

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /
```

actually worked

now on to the next problem ..